# Android File Transfer is not working on macOS since I upgraded to Ventura

Tags: mac, android, data-transfer

My MacBook Pro is now running Ventura 13.5.

I am no longer able to use the AFT app (android file transfer) to upload media from my Galaxy S21 phone to my Mac using a USB-C cable this process used to work

I have uninstalled and reinstalled the AFT app on macOS but no affect. I still the message:

> ‘No android device found.’

Yes, I have enabled debugging mode on the Samsung Galaxy S21.

Answer (score 4):

Some suggestion from the article
[How to Fix Android File Transfer Not Working on macOS Ventura](https://www.saintlad.com/android-file-transfer-not-working-on-macos-ventura/):

- Restart both the Mac and mobile phone
- Close Google Drive and the Preview app
- Enable USB Debugging on an Android phone
- Check that the Mac's USB preference is not set to 'Charge only'
- Ensure that the Mac or phone software is fully updated
- Reinstall the Android File Transfer software on the Mac.

You will find more details with screenshots in the linked article.

Comment: still not working. i was hoping the suggestion to close google drive app would make a difference.

Im amazed that 2 giant platforms ,  apple macos and samsung/android , cant agree to allow a seemless way to connect via usb-c.

Comment: I have seen the same suggestions repeated in other sources. Disabling the Preview app specifically was often cited by people as the solution that fixed it. Perhaps it worked once but not any more. Sorry I couldn't be of more help.

Comment: For unknown reasons, it works for me on one Mac but not working on the other one. Which is very strange, and I was not able to solve it. But it is certain that the issue is on Mac's side.

Comment: Please don't downvote an answer that works for some people, even if it didn't work for you.

Comment: I agree. Your post directed me to the solution.

Comment: "Close Google Drive and the Preview app" THANK YOU!!!

Answer (score 2):

I was able to solve it.

1. On Mac, go into System settings… > General > Login Items
2. Remove all apps in 'Open at login' and leave only the Android File Transfer Agent.
3. Disable all apps in 'Allow in the Background'
4. Shutdown computer and turn it on again

Those steps helped me, so probably some app blocked USB.